# How to create a blazor framework client side app which should deploy as static files

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web-frameworks, blazor

I have to create a static pages site using blazor framework. what is the command for this.

I have installed dotnet core sdk 3.0 preview and tried to create a blazor app using the command

> "dotnet new blazor"

.

--- below is the output of the command execution --

> dotnet new blazor The template "Blazor (server-side)" was created
>   successfully.
>
> Processing post-creation actions... Running 'dotnet restore' on
>   C:\Users\user\Documents\VS_CODE\blazoring\blazoring.csproj...
>   Restore completed in 206.18 ms for
>   C:\Users\user\Documents\VS_CODE\blazoring\blazoring.csproj.
>
> Restore succeeded.

---

I hoped that it will generate only static pages.but it is not doing so, it is generating server side app and deploying through localhost:5000

Comment: There is probably no template for it yet. I didn't read this but it sounds like what you want https://anthonychu.ca/post/blazor-azure-storage-static-websites/

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've not got the right templates installed. In order to get the correct Blazor templates you can use the following command.

```
dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::3.0.0-preview5-19227-01
```

Once you have the Blazor template installed you can create a stand alone client-side Blazor app using the following command.

```
dotnet new blazor
```

To publish this and get the static files you then need to use the following command inside the same directory as the applications .csproj file.

```
dotnet publish -c release
```

You should then find all the static files you need in the following directory.

```
\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\publish\<projectname>\dist
```

I would suggest you have a read of the offical documentation on hosting client-side Blazor which you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/blazor/client-side?view=aspnetcore-3.0). I've also written a couple of blog posts about publishing Blazor apps using Azure pipelines which you can find [here](https://chrissainty.com/building-blazor-apps-using-azure-pipelines/), if it's of interest.

Comment: this generated a little different templet but running fully only through localhost:5000,on dotnet run, static page in release folder is only the index.html without layouts

Comment: I'm use sure of what you mean, Blazor is a SPA framework hence you will only have a index.html once the application is compiled. Your indvidual components will be compiled into the dlls.

Comment: then how to access them as static page ,if they will be served through servers then what is the advantage of using blazor over js html and css

Comment: The contents of the `dist` directory is static files. They can be placed on any webserver and they will work without needing .NET Core installed. I really would suggest you read the hosting section on the Blazor documentation I linked to or read my articles on deploying Blazor apps.

Comment: @sikka karma html, js and css are also served by web servers. What is it that you think a "static" site is?